# What is this struct trying to do?

Tags: c++, struct

In the following `C++` code:

```
struct Features {
  int F1;
  int F2;
  int F3;
  int F4;
  Features(int F1,int F2,int F3,int F4)
  : F1(F1), F2(F2), F3(F3), F4(F4) { }
};
```

What does this part mean?

```
Features(int F1,int F2,int F3,int F4)
      : F1(F1), F2(F2), F3(F3), F4(F4) { }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is initializing the member variables using the constructor's initializer list. it would be clearer if the names of the constructor parameters weren't the same as the data members:

```
Features(int a,int b,int c,int d)
      : F1(a), F2(b), F3(c), F4(d) { }
```

It is useful to have some naming convention for data members, such that these are easily identifiable and distinguishable from local variables in code. Examples are prefixing an `m_` or using a trailing `_`:

```
struct Features {
  int m_f1;
  int m_f2;
  int m_3f;
  int m_f4;
  Features(int f1,int f2,int f3,int f4)
  : m_f1(f1), m_f2(f2), m_f3(f3), m_f4(f4) { }
};
```

Both these constructors can be used like this:

```
Features f(11,22,33,44);
std::cout << f.m_f1 << "\n"; // prints 11
std::cout << f.m_f2 << "\n"; // prints 22
std::cout << f.m_f3 << "\n"; // prints 33
std::cout << f.m_f4 << "\n"; // prints 44
```

Note that the fact that this constructor has been defined means that the compiler will no longer provide a default constructor. So if you want to be able to to this:

```
Features f;
```

then you need to provide your own default constructor:

```
Features() : m_f1(), m_f2(), m_f3(), m_f4() {} // initializes data members to 0
```

Comment: I am sure you know that juancho, but for clarity: They are not the same, as C++ is case sensitive. `f1` is not `F1`.

Comment: @juanchopanza. In this case, what are we initializing the mamber variables to? In other words, what values are the member variables having here? Will they have the value `0` since they are of `int` type?

Comment: They are initialized to the arguments passed to `Features`'s constructor. I added a little example.

Comment: @Med-SWEng : when you create a struct `Features`, you have to put the four values. An example : `Features f(5,4,2,9);` if you don tdo that, you can not create the struct (no default constructor specified), exactly as a class with no default constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza. Why do you add `{ }` at the end of the initialization?

Comment: @Med-SWEng hte `{}` is the body of the constructor. It is empty in these examples but it could contain code.

Answer (score 2):

It is member variables initialization

You could do it this way:

```
Features(int F1,int F2,int F3,int F4)
{
    this->F1 = F1;
    this->F2 = F2;
    this->F3 = F3;
    this->F4 = F4;
}
```

But

```
Features(int F1,int F2,int F3,int F4)
      : F1(F1), F2(F2), F3(F3), F4(F4) { }
```

Is preferred, because for user defined types default constructor will invoked automatically and can give you some overhead. In case your member variables do not have default constructor it is necessary to initialize them in initializer list. Constant fields must be initialized in the initializer list as well

And also I think it's just more clear to use initialization lists

Comment: You might want to say why it is preferred (ie: because the members are guaranteed to be initialized)

Comment: @PauldeLange: I'm saying, but typing speed is limited )

Answer (score 1):

Give [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) a read. It should answer your question.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why? The tutorial I linked in the answer contains a detailed explanation to the question.

Comment: The other posts answer the question right here, which is preferred and get more votes. Links are for Google.

Comment: OK, agreed. I don't get any upvotes for a hasty answer, but why downvotes?

Comment: Some people might think you didn't answer the question `What does this part mean?`. The other posts do that more directly. You could have said something like "It is a constructor with an initializer list, providing initial values for the struct members. Read all about constructors here.".

Comment: I see. Well, I'll try to be a bit more precise next time, even though I still dislike seeing that some people don't even bother going through a short language-specific programming tutorial before asking questions.